# NGRX component-store effect is looped by calling patchState

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-component-store

My effect loops infinitely, and I'm not sure why.

```js
  interface LatestAppointmentsWidgetState {
    loading: boolean;
    page: number;
    pagedData: Paged<Appointment>;
  }

  @Injectable()
  export class LatestAppointmentsWidgetStore extends ComponentStore<LatestAppointmentsWidgetState> {

  private readonly params$ = this.select(state => ({
    page: state.page
  }));

  readonly loadBusinesses = this.effect(() => {
    return this.params$.pipe(
      tap({ next: () => this.patchState({ loading: true }) })
    );
  });
}
```

I've tried to only keep the relevant code. It seems that the patchState within the effect triggers the `params$` selector. But from my understanding patchState should only update the state that matches the partial state passed as an argument. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because:

1. patch state updates the state
2. the selector "reacts" the new state
3. the selector creates a new instance
4. because of the new instance the effect is retriggered

In order to prevent this consider just returning the boolean value.

```
  private readonly page$ = this.select(state => state.page);

  // you can use it to recreate params$
  private readonly params$ = this.select(this.page$, page => ({page});
```

A second option is to make the effect "smarter" and ignore re-emits, e.g. by using `distinct(By)`.